# Is there an automated way of finding which page, of a paginated list, contains a specific object?

Tags: django, pagination

After the user creates a new object, I want to redirect them back the paginated list of objects.  Importantly I want to send them to the page of the list where the newly create object is shown (so that I can highlight it).

Is there an good way of doing this built into Django, or in a library?

[MySql paginated results, find "page" for specific result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086719/mysql-paginated-results-find-page-for-specific-result) is relevant, but I'm looking for best-practise for a Django app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "automated" way because objects aren't inherently tied to the concept of a "page". Additionally, the ordering of a queryset is variable, so the page number of a particular object is as well. However, you can pretty readily adapt that answer to Django's DBAPI, essentially:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(my_order_by_field__lt=my_instance.my_order_by_field).count()
```

Then, just divide that by your items per page:

```
page_number = count / items_per_page
```

Since, Python's `/` operator already floors when dealing with ints, you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Thanks, I expect I'll need to +1 as pagination starts at 1.