# MongoDB finding page number of specific record

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I have a paged records in MongoDB for which I want to look up a specific record, and find out which page it relies on. Let's say where *name = Foobar* in a phonebook, and count per page is 1000 records.

This has been [solved with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086719/mysql-paginated-results-find-page-for-specific-result), where the correct answer relies on the logic of:

1. get the total count of records where `name < $searchName`,
2. then divide by the number of records per page.

To my knowledge, MongoDB doesn't support using `lessthan` with strings, so I can't do something like:

```
find({ 'name': { $lt : 'Foobar' } }).count();
```

How can I do something similar to the MySql answer with Mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does support comparing strings with `$lt` and other comparison operators. Note that there are some limitations regarding locales, as it compares strings using their UTF-8 representation, but it works fine in the POSIX locale.

You should check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imCCKOevU3c) to learn more about how this works.

So yes, you should be able to run a query like:

`db.collection.find({ "name" : { $lt : "Foobar" }}).count();`

And then you can follow the logic you describe in your post.

PS. Note that you have an extra opening bracket and are missing a closing bracket in your query.